# "Une nouvelle de 2nde"?

Tags: sens

I am new to French. I have only studied for a few weeks. When I consult the dictionary I can not find the answer.

> Théo: Qui est la fille là-bas avec les cheveaux roux?
>
> Jules: C'est Stéphanie. Une nouvelle de 2nde.

Question: What does "Une nouvelle de 2nde." mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentence, *de* indicates belonging and 2<sup>de</sup> (which is preferred to 2<sup>nde</sup> according to the [Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/abreviations-des-adjectifs-numeraux)) is the abbreviation of *seconde*, which is the first class of the *lycée*, which is the French equivalent of high school. In *seconde*, students are generally 15 to 16 years old.

So a good translation would be (assuming you're American):

> Jules: That's Stéphanie. A new girl in 10th grade.

Answer (score 1):

2nde, or better 2<sup>de</sup>, is a shortcut for *seconde*, like the English 2<sup>nd</sup>. Here it means *classe de seconde*, the first class of French high school (similar to the US K10 grade).